# Can't return char in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my code:

```
char pattern(int x){
  if (x < 13){
    return "a";
  }
  if (x < 26){
    return "b";
  }
}
```

The error is `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int'`
I tried searching for the error online but all the resources are only for C. Please advice.

Comment: What is the type of a ***string*** literal like `"a"`? Think about the difference between `"a"` and `'a'`.

Comment: Furthermore, what if neither condition is true, what will you return then? If you declare a function to return a value, you *must* return a value, always. Otherwise you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Lastly please try to avoid [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). What do the numbers `13` and `26` actually mean? Create symbolic constants with suitable names for those values instead. Will make it much easier to read and understand the code.

Comment: I see this confusion a lot coming from persons who have used JavaScript or some other language that treats single and double quotes as the same thing.  In C++, there is a vast difference between `"a"` and `'a'`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that double quotes mean "C string". What you need to return is the character "a", which in C++ is `'a'`, and character "b", which is `'b'`. Try this:

```
char pattern(int x){
  if (x < 13){
    return 'a';
  }
  if (x < 26){
    return 'b';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**use this code**

```
char pattern(int x){
  if (x < 13){
    return 'a';
  }
  if (x < 26){
    return 'b';
  }
}
```

use 'a' instead of "a" asnd same for b